# How to have an edittext with constant hint and icon and editable hint?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I want to have an edittext with image below:
[image]

How can I have an edittext like this? A constant icon and hint with editable area like 'James25' in picture. I just want to edit name and mail part.

I am working on an XML file for Android app.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it using one textView and edittext with gravity end like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_cross_prime"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="UserName"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvUserName"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_cross_prime"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="UserName"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvEmail"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18" />

</RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is okay but I don't want to do it with nested layouts. Any other solution?

Comment: thats not possible with one edit text but if you want to show the icon and hint and than you click on edit text the hint gone and the text show or hint should move up thats possible with on edit text